# If Cell number 123456 contains 1 Then put x in cell if not blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently struggling to find a formula that would assist my current situation. I've searched the internet trying count and find statements, but coming up empty handed.

Situation: i'm provided a worksheet with over 4000 rows, a cell contains Raw data of "1234567" - 1 being monday, 2 tuesday..etc. However, the cell may contain just "124" or "145" Depending on the days operation occurs.

I need to convert this into a row of 7 cells listed 1-7. If the raw data contains a 1, put a x in column 1, if 2 put a x in column 2 and so on.

My closest is =IF("1",L7),"x","") . However, if the value isnt found i get '#value!'. I need the field to remain blank if not found.

I've attached a image to explain better.

Any help would be welcomed. manually entering x in 4000 rows is hell.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKLHk.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$1,$A2)),"x","")
```

Comment: You are the best!